# Adicionar usuário do Wordpress em mais de uma função

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para área de membros no WordPress e vou controlar esse acesso através das funções (*roles*).

Supondo que eu crie as funções: conteudo1, conteudo2 e conteudo3. Como eu conseguiria atribuir mais de uma função para um usuário criado?

```
$website = site_url();

$cliente_userdata = array(
    'first_name' => 'Primeiro Nome',
    'user_login'  =>  'E-mail',
    'user_email' => 'E-mail',
    'user_url'    =>  $website,
    'role' => 'conteudo1',
    'user_pass'   =>  NULL // Cria Sózinho
);

wp_insert_user( $cliente_userdata ) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diretamente acho que é impossível. [A documentação é extremamente rasa](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), ela diz o seguinte

> A string used to set the user's role.

Em tradução livre

> String usada para "*setar*" a "*role*" do usuário

Pelo menos pra mim, isso dá a entender que só é possível passar uma *role* e pronto. Eu **tentaria** passar dois valores separados por vírgula, não sei se funciona, é só uma dica.

De qualquer forma é possível adicionar as *roles* depois de criar o usuário

```
$userid = wp_insert_user($userdata);
$user = new WP_User($userid);
$user->add_role('conteudo1');
$user->add_role('conteudo2');
```

Comment: passar valores separados por vírgula não vai funcionar. `add_role()` sim.

Comment: Funcionou dessa forma, obrigado!